# CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL for curl_multi

Tags: php, curl, curl-multi

I'm using PHP's CURL MULTI to download an array of resources in parallel, and I want to get the last effective URL from *each* of the resources (not just the last one).

Basically, I'm looking for:

```
curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
```

for CURL MULTI, something like:

```
curl_multi_getinfo($ch[$key], CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but `curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);` should work just fine with the multi_* functions.

The key thing here is that `$ch` is an individual handle that *you* keep track of. So `curl_getinfo($ch[$key], CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);` would be a possible implementation if `$ch` was an array of curl handles.

Comment: While playing around some more, I noticed that `curl_getinfo($ch[$key])` was returning the normal array of info, but because I have most of the return options turned off I didn't notice that the url wasn't coming back either--which led me to discover that I wasn't even initializing the URLs correctly in the first place. It works now, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL
```

This paramter is not reliable for referencing your original url list. It can return a different url from from the url provided in CURLOPT_URL.